# CXF service proxies cause NullPointerException when passed null array

Tags: java, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

Via using CXF 2.7.11 via Maven with the cxf-java2ws-plugin and cxf-codegen-plugin, a WSDL gets generated from a web service class and from that WSDL proxy classes are generated which then get used in various clients to connect to the actual, live server.

There is a problem with these generated service proxies in that they cause a NullPointerException when passed a null array.

The web service is something like this:

```
public class MyService {
    public SomeResult someMethod(String param, String[] otherParams) {
      if (otherParams == null){
        ... etc etc...
      }
    }
}
```

A generated WSDL fragment:

```
<xs:complexType name="someMethod">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="param1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="otherParams" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And finally a generated service proxy fragment :

```
public class SomeMethod
{

    protected String param1;
    protected String[] otherParams;

    ...

    public String[] getOtherParams()
    {
        // Good, defensive code used here
        if (this.otherParams == null)
        {
            return new String[0];
        }
        String[] retVal = new String[this.otherParams.length];
        System.arraycopy(this.otherParams, 0, retVal, 0, this.otherParams.length);
        return (retVal);
    }

    ...

    public void setOtherParams(String[] values)
    {
        // Complete lack of defensive code here!
        int len = values.length;
        this.otherParams = ((String[]) new String[len]);
        for (int i = 0; (i < len); i++)
        {
            this.otherParams[i] = values[i];
        }
    }

    public String setOtherParams(int idx,
            String value)
    {
        // And here
        return this.otherParams[idx] = value;
    }
}
```

pom.xml fragment for WSDL generation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>generate-wsdl-MyService</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java2ws</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <className>com.somewhere.services.MyService</className>
            <serviceName>MyService</serviceName>
            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<plugin>
```

pom.xml fragment for proxy generation from above WSDL:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-service-proxies</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>some/location/jaxws-binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                        <bindingFile>some/location/jaxb-binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </defaultOptions>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>some/location/generated/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How do I get CXF to generate service proxies that cope with clients wishing to pass a null array? (Not an empty array or array containing nulls, an actual null array). Do I need "otherParams" declared as "nillable=true" in the WSDL? If so, how?

I have tried many annotations and JAXB/JAXWS options and can't seem to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: maybe you missed a ``nillable="true"`` in the wsdl?

Comment: I'm not creating the WSDL, they are auto-generated as part of the Maven run and I cannot get it to include `nillable="true"` Do you know how to get that directive included?